# Failed to deploy to Google App Engine because --use_java7 flag has not been set

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

> ------------ Deploying frontend ------------
>
> Preparing to deploy:  Created staging directory at:
>   'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg2555411734473986257.tmp'
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes,
>   but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.
>
> Debugging information may be found in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy7182870224187999057.log

Debug Log:

> Unable to update:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:576)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
>       at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
>       at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

I'm attempting to deploy a google app to my google app engine account and eclipse is giving me this error. It seems rather straight forward, but I can't find where to set a flag for java7.

I'm using the latest version of Eclipse (Juno Service Release 1) and my google plugin is 4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [1.7.3 blog post](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/10/app-engine-173-released.html):

> In an upcoming release, we will be including some of the new Java 7
>   functionality as well as formal Java 7 support within the App Engine
>   Java runtime.

and...

> And while Java 7 support is not yet available within the App Engine
>   Java runtime, developers interested in an early preview can sign up
>   for our [trusted tester program](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/viewform?id=13UvQiEjr7ob-QXMSFch5LByQN8vHa70Rl98g8ipCf9c).

You'll need to either be accepted into the TT program, or to wait for a future release where Java 7 works in production.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I suppose I'll keep it on a localhost for the time being!

Answer (score 2):

The relevant system level property is shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/AppCfg.java?r=290): com.google.apphosting.runtime.use_java7

It can be passed into appCfg.sh like so:

```
appcfg.sh --use_java7 update
```

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge here, but how can I go about editing it? I've searched around for appcfg.sh, or some sort of command prompt, but to no avail.

Comment: Here is how to run it from command line without the plugin: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp

If you are using the plugin there is a section at the bottom here that tells you how to find and use appcfg from within the eclipse plugin directory: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/eclipse

That said, if you aren't in the TT program you will likely get an error even with those flags set.