# How to switch from Java 7 to Java 6 in Eclipse for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have developed a small application with Google Web Toolkit and would like to deploy it to the Google App Engine (GAE) server. I'm using Eclipse Juno and Java 7 by default, but when I tried to deploy to GAE, I realised that it does not support Java 7 yet. So I switched to a Java 6 JRE in the project setting (set Build Path/Libraries to "java-6-openjdk-amd64" and Java Compiler/Compiler compliance level to 1.6.

However, when I try to deploy my app via the Google Eclipse plugin, it still throws the same RuntimeException:

> "The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has
>   not been set."

Here's the complete debugging output:

```
Unable to update:
java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.Application.createStagingDirectory(Application.java:576)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:370)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:53)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
        at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

How can I remove the Java 7 remainders so that the Google plugin understands?

This is all running on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit.

Comment: Have you "Cleaned" your project before deploying? Project -> Clean

Comment: Yes, I did. No difference though. :(

Comment: Try to start eclipse with a java 6 **JDK** as explained here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Linux_Example . Use the JDK instead of the JRE, because the GAE only works with a Java JDK (Version 6 or below).

Comment: Done, with no luck though. I added the two lines `-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/bin/java' to eclipse.ini, did a Clean and re-compiled the project, still the error remains. The file exists and is in a JDK.

Comment: Project -> Properties -> Project Facets -> Java is set to 1.6?

Comment: Yes, it is, with the Java 6 JRE runtime checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using your Java 7 installation to compile. In eclipse, go to *Window > Preferences*. In there, browse to *Java > Installed JREs*.

The list on the right probably only shows the jre/jdk7 in your case. You have to add your installation of Java 5 or 6 in here, and make sure that it is the "ticked" JRE.

Afterwards, use *Project > Clean...*, select "Clean All Projects" and make sure that "Start a build immediatly" is ticked, along with "build the entire workspace".

[Edit : this answer is not accurate for android development... When I realized that, a quck search showed that the question looks suspiciously close to [Failed to deploy to Google App Engine because --use_java7 flag has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848495/failed-to-deploy-to-google-app-engine-because-use-java7-flag-has-not-been-set) , the answer is probably the same.]

Comment: Done that, reluctantly however because my other projects actually require Java 7, but it brings some sort of progress. Alas, when I do a Clean now, I get a RuntimeException "Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/schnobo/entropie/client/Entropie : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0". This clearly indicates that something still has been compiled by the Java 7 compiler, but I think I already have removed all the pointers to Java 7 in my Eclipse settings.

Comment: You are getting this exception during the "clean"? Seems more like something that should pop up at runtime. I don't really know about your environment : the question I linked in my edit mentions that the GAE uses some Java 7 functionality, meaning that it is compiled against jdk 7 and can only run under Java 7 itself... the vm under which your program run should thus be java 7... and this exception tells us otherwise (it is thrown when running a class compiled with java n with an earlier vm). Without a better understanding of the environment, I'm afraid I cannot answer meaningfully.

Comment: I assume that this exception is actually raised during the build performed automatically after the clean. I'm afraid I will try and start a new Java 7 project, copying all the files manually, and see how this works out.

Comment: If this is indeed raised by the "clean"... it only makes sense if that happends during the compilation of a class that depends on the com.schnobo.entropie.client.Entropie class. And that would mean that you are either not cleaning the whole workspace (at least, you are not cleaning the project that contains this "Entropie" class), or that you are trying to compile a class X with Java 6 while this class depends on a third-party library (Entropie) that is itself compiled under Java 7... which is impossible. If the library you depend on is compiled for 7, yours must compile for 7.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could finally help it was to create a new project in Eclipse, switch to Java 6 immediately (Build Path, Compiler, Java facet), and copy/paste all the files and GAE settings from the previous project.