# How to set --use_java7 flag for Googleappengine

Tags: google-app-engine

My appengine deploy failed because --use_java 7 flag wasn't set. I tried opening the command line and going to: plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7/bin  and running  appcfg.sh --use_java 7. This didn't work. What will. All the answers in this link didn't work [Failed to deploy to Google App Engine because --use_java7 flag has not been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848495/failed-to-deploy-to-google-app-engine-because-use-java7-flag-has-not-been-set)

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message you have when adding the `--use_java7` option?

Comment: VonC ----------- Deploying frontend ------------

Preparing to deploy:
 Created staging directory at: 'C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\appcfg1816285276627693297.tmp'
java.lang.RuntimeException: The application contains Java 7 classes, but the --use_java7 flag has not been set.

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy2052309787802951704.log

Comment: So it is like it ignores the `--use_java7` option? Can you paste the command you used when launching `appcg.py`?

Comment: in this directory eclipse\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.7\appengine-java-sdk-1.7.7\bin   I ran this command appcfg.sh --use_java7 update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally had the sense to re-install Google app-engine's latest version which was compatible with 1.77. Whatever the problem was it was solved.

Too all Google representatives: some newbies like me are not familiar with the command line. I recommend you add the uninstall option for the app-engine and any files outside the eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

With 1.7.7, deployment is happening now on a java7 runtime, so this temporary flag has now been removed.
Just remove it.